# Angular JS Image validation max size and valid format

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I want to show different validation message for maximum size and invalid format in image upload.
Here is my code, but max size validation is not working,show only invalid file format validation.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="group-row col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1">
    <input class="control-set" type="file" ngf-select ng-model="image" name="image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="5MB" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-min-size='1' ui-jq="filestyle">
    <div ng-show="createUserForm.$submitted || createUserForm.image.$invalid" ng-model="image">
         <span ng-show="createUserForm.image.maxSize" class="text-danger">File must be less than 5 MB.</span>
         <span ng-show="createUserForm.image.$invalid" class="text-danger">Only .jpg,jpeg and .png images are allowed.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i made mistake here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show error using createUserForm.image.**$error.maxSize**
missing $error

```
<span ng-show="createUserForm.image.$error.maxSize" class="text-danger">File must be less than 5 MB.</span>
```

Comment: another problem is both the message show if upload large image with valid format

`<span ng-show="createCompanyForm.image.$invalid" class="text-danger">Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png images are allowed.</span>
                            <span ng-show="createCompanyForm.image.$error.maxSize" class="text-danger">File must be less than 2 MB.</span`

Comment: i solved the issue by adding `createCompanyForm.image.$error.pattern`